# In tensorflow graph mode, why doesn't tensor.shape work, but tf.shape(tensor) does?

Tags: tensorflow

In tensorflow, when running something in graph mode, tensor.shape does not work, but tf.shape(Tensor) does.

I am wondering if there's any reason for this.

Comment: you need to be more specific. 
1) Are you using tf 2.0 in auto graph mode?
2) what do you mean by "does not work"?
Share the code